# uploading image to server with nextjs Api Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, upload, multipartform-data

Hello guys I have been trying to send image from input into my Api with Nextjs And I have problem
my server does not send any respond to me or better say it's not even send to server
first I send data to my Api Route and then parse it with formidable after that send it again to server
I have tried many third-person library I don't know if I should parse my data in API Route or not

my uploadfile.js component

```js
         import React, { useEffect } from "react";
         import { useRef } from "react";
         
         const CardProfile = (props) => {
           const { profile } = props;
           const fileUploader = useRef();
           const [dataBaseResponse, setDataBaseResponse] = React.useState({});
           const profileTrigger = (event) => {
             event.preventDefault();
             fileUploader.current.click();
           };
         
           const sendProfile =  async (event) => {
             console.log(fileUploader.current.files[0]);
             const formData = new FormData();
             formData.append("image", fileUploader.current.files[0]);
              fetch("/api/changeUserProfile", {
               method: "POST",
               body: formData,
             }).then(async (response) => {
               await response.json().then((data) => {
                 setDataBaseResponse({
                   message: data.message,
                   data,
                 });
                 console.log(dataBaseResponse);
               });
             });
             console.log(dataBaseResponse);
           };
               
           return (
             <div>
               <input
                 id="js-file-uploader"
                 ref={fileUploader}
                 onChange={sendProfile}
                 className={style.hidden}
                 name="profile-picture"
                 type="file"
                 accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
               />
            </div>
          );
        };
        
        export default CardProfile;
```

and my api route  /api/changeUserProfile.js

```js
   import formidable from 'formidable';
   import FormData from "form-data";
   
   export const config = {
     api: {
       bodyParser: false,
     },
   };
   export default async function changeUserProfile(req, res) {
     if (req.method === "POST") {
       
       const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.keepExtensions = true;
       form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
         console.log(files.image);
        const forms = new FormData();
       forms.append( "image", files.image );
       fetch("https://auth.megaverse.today/api/v1/user/uploadProfileImage", {
         method: "POST",
         headers: {
           Cookie: req.headers.cookie,
         },
         body: forms,
       })
         .then((response) => {
           response.json().then((data) => {
             res.json(data);
             console.log(data);
           });
         })
         .catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
         });
       });      
       
     }
   }
```

I have tried multiparty and formidable but I can't upload it
please help me to find my problem

Answer (score 0):

In formidable "If the directory does not exist, the uploaded files are silently discarded."
In my case, formidable was creating a file locally but not on the server. This was happening because the upload directory route was different for development and production.
In formidable you can change the upload directory by passing uploadDir parameter to IncomingForm in formidable.

`const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({uploadDir:` ${process.cwd()}`});`

Also, to see if there is an error in formidable console log the err,

```
form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
  if(err){
    console.log("err is:",err)
  }else{
      const data = fs.readFileSync(file.filepath);
      await fs.writeFile(`${location}/`+ file.originalFilename, data, ()=>console.log("writing done"))
  }
  return res.send({"status":200});
}
});
```